# What is the name of graph problem that ask to select some vertices to see every edges.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

I want to place light bulbs on some vertices (each bulb will lit up every edges it connected) where all edges lit up.

e.g. suppose I have this simple planar graph,

[image: 7-wheel graph]

Sufficient vertices to place those light bulbs are $\{0, 1, 3, 5\}$.

---

At first I think this is [art gallery problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem), but they focus on seeing every vertices, not edges. Or I need some kind of graph transformation to fit my problem into it?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a [vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover).

Comment: I must confess, since I'm from non-English spoken country, I think the problem name should be edge covered. XD

Comment: Well, a vertex cover has vertices as the "covers". The edge covering problem is the other way around: You find a set of edges in which every vertex is adjacent to at least one edge. The problems seem similar but are very different in terms of difficulty. In summary: If you want to light up edges using vertices, you want a vertex cover. If you want to light up vertices using edges, you want an edge cover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the [minimum vertex cover problem](http://www.eng.tau.ac.il/algs/intro-vc.pdf)?  This document contains some information about the restriction of the problem to planar graphs.